# How to make a folder stored in internal memory more secure

Tags: android

In our application we are downloading files and saving it inside application memory(/data/data/package/files) using

```
String path=getFilesDir().getPath();
```

Now for rooted devices,the user can read through the files downloaded.But what we require is to make the folder protected so that the user cannot view the files even for rooted devices.

I have gone through file encryption and decryption process using "AES" but it is taking time as file size increases.

Please let us know any better solution as how i can achieve this.